# Data not being set in AJAX

Tags: php, ajax

Why doesn't this work? I'm trying to send some data to the server via AJAX but it doesn't show up there.

The console just logs `abc`, no sign of the `123`.

The AJAX call

```js
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        console.log(this.responseText);
    }
};
xmlhttp.open("GET", "includes/process_login.php?email=123", true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

and _process_login.php_ is:

```php
<?php

include_once 'db_connect.php';
include_once 'functions.php';

sec_session_start(); // Our custom secure way of starting a PHP session.


echo($_GET['email']."abc");
exit();
```

Answer (score 0):

After testing your code it is understood that there's no problem with your `ajax` code the only problem is with your php function `sec_session_start();` surely it is not a built-in function if you remove it your code runs.

**Output**

[image]

> Our custom secure way of starting a PHP session.

And even then if you want to keep your function please check it the code stops right there.

Comment: Ah thanks. It's from Part 4 here https://www.wikihow.com/Create-a-Secure-Login-Script-in-PHP-and-MySQL. They say that you need it because php sessions are known not be secure. I have no idea how to amend this to deal with the problem that it's causing.

Comment: Right now when i click on the link it says that the site is under quality review so i cannot visit it.

Comment: Ok think i've got your code just tell me after this are you been redirected to `Location: ../error.php?err=Could not initiate a safe session (ini_set)`

Comment: I thought that all I had to do was say that I accepted it. Is there a button that I have to press as well?

Comment: Yes a check mark sign under the votes section of answer.

Comment: Yes a check mark sign under the votes section of answer.